# How to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE in a nested transaction in PostgreSQL (plpgsql)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions, plpgsql

Within a plpgsql stored procedure, I am attempting to write to a list of hosts (using PL/Proxy - unrelated to this problem) based on an *active* column in table `A`, where `A` contains a column *host* and column *active* which indicates whether or not the host is alive and should be written to (for each row in `A` where `active = TRUE`, `write_to_host(A.host)`). The function `write_hosts` reads from the `A` table and only chooses the hosts that are marked `active=TRUE` .

Upon catching an exception while attempting to write to one of the hosts, I want to update table `A`, setting `A.active = FALSE WHERE A.host = <badhost>`, and continue attempting to write to the other hosts. It looked something like the following, where I wanted to attempt the insert, fail, update the `A` table marking the row as inactive, then recursively call the `write_doc` function, which should see the remaining *active* entries and only attempt to write to them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION write_doc(args...)
RETURNS SETOF JSON AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM write_to_host(args...);

    RETURN NEXT ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY[TRUE::text, 'inserted']);
    RETURN;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLERRM ~ '.+Connection refused.+' THEN
            EXECUTE 'UPDATE hosts SET active = FALSE WHERE host = ''' || _bad_host || '''';
END;
            RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM write_doc(args...);
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This results in an infinite loop, which I have to CNTRL-C out of.

When I comment out the `RETURN QUERY` bit, the deactivation works for the host in question. When I leave it in, table `A` is not updated (at least not before I stop the execution of the procedure).

Using an alternative method with a LOOP, it still ends up looping infinitely for me, and table `A` is not updated... something like the following, where the *RETURN* statement should exit the loop:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION write_doc(args...)
RETURNS SETOF JSON AS $$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM write_to_host(args...);

            RETURN NEXT ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY[TRUE::text, 'inserted']);
            RETURN;

        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SQLERRM ~ '.+Connection refused.+' THEN
                EXECUTE 'UPDATE hosts SET active = FALSE WHERE host = ''' || _bad_host || '''';
END;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I understand that all stored procedures are transactional, but thought that the table would be updated within the transaction and would be viewable by the code running in the stored procedure, guess I am wrong?

Any suggestions/information someone can give to lead me in the right direction? Any questions don't hesitate to ask

Comment: On first reading, this sounds like it might be simpler and more direct with a cursor.

Comment: At a quick skim-read, are you attempting to implement an upsert/merge?

Comment: Question has been copied and pasted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/66104/7788. Please delete the other copy and keep this one.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Didn't realize searches across both sites worked, my apologies. I have deleted the entry on dba.stackexchange. As for the upsert/merge, it's more like a retry. The 'check' that it performs (`SELECT host FROM A WHERE active = TRUE`) to attempt any action would be re-run, which means that if the table were updated, the host that was most recently marked as inactive would not be returned